# SSRS - "Content" field doesn't update for data source when connection string is updated?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I'm currently building an SSRS audit that checks the "Content" field in the Reporting Database's Catalog table. I've noticed that when a data source's connection string is updated to a different server or db after being deployed, the Content field in the database will continue showing the old connection string - however, other fields such as the name or path update immediately. I haven't been able to find anything online about this - has anyone experienced anything similar?

My environment is SSRS 2012 & SQL Server 2012.

The query I'm using to read the Content is:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Content), 4, LEN(CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), Content))))) AS Content
FROM Catalog
WHERE Type = 5
```

Comment: When you go back and view the data source settings on the reporting server (through the web portal), do the changes you made persist?

Comment: @yelxe Yes, the changes persist on ReportManager.